# IntelliJ PhpStorm/Idea : Access deployment server informations programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea, phpstorm, intellij-plugin

I'm desperate trying to acces to the server list and configuration accessible by the configuration / deployment window.

I tryed :

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList<RunnerAndConfigurationSettings>();
for (RemoteServer<?> server : RemoteServersManagerImpl.getInstance().getServers()) {
    result.add(server);
}
```

But I got an empty list, also I tried to instanciate the DeploymentConfigurator out of a tree view...no results also.

*Please can you help me finding the correct object to get singleton, it will be so gracefull! Thank you very much in advance.*